# How to find button with Selenium by its text inside (Java)?

Tags: java, angular, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I have a button like below. I am not sure how to grab it by it's text which is **Search**. There are many buttons on this page.

```
<button _ngcontent-dqg-c23="" class="cp-mat-small-btn mat-flat-button mat-accent" color="accent" mat-flat-button="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-color="accent"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
    Search
  </span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

I tried :

```
WebElement searchBtn = webDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Search"]');
```

But getting error:

```
    | > Task :compileTestJava
gauge_1          | /tipu/src/test/java/CalmImplementation.java:16: error: unclosed character literal
gauge_1          |         WebElement searchBtn = webDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Search"]');
gauge_1          |                                                                ^
gauge_1          | /tipu/src/test/java/CalmImplementation.java.java:16: error: unclosed character literal
gauge_1          |         WebElement searchBtn = webDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Search"]');
gauge_1          |                                                                                                     ^
gauge_1          | /tipu/src/test/java/CalmImplementation.java.java:16: error: not a statement
gauge_1          |         WebElement searchBtn = webDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Search"]');
gauge_1          |                                                                         ^
gauge_1          | 3 errors
gauge_1          |
```

Comment: Try to find button with the class atribute. Then just use 
webElement.getText()

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many buttons with same class and none of them has id.

Comment: no worries. Yo can use 
for(int i=0; i<driver.findelements(By.xpath("//whatever")).size();i++)  

{ 
     if (driver.findelements(By.xpath("//whatever")).get(i).getText().contains("Search")) 
     {
             driver.findelements(By.xpath("//whatever")).get(i).click();
             break;
      } 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath()` isn't a valid method when using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s *Java* client.

Again, the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with text as **Search** is within the child `<span>` of it's parent `<button>` and an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element.

So to identify the element by it's text i.e. **Search** you you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath` and `contains()`:

  ```
  WebElement searchBtn = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(., 'Search')]")));
  ```
- Using `xpath` and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  WebElement searchBtn = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button/span[normalize-space()='Search']")));
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPATH:

```
//button[normalize-space()="Search"]
```

Note that search by `text()="Search"` won't work as button text is not exactly `"Search"` - text content contains linesbreaks/spaces